# Maximal ideals of a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I'm trying to show that the following ring is not local:
$R = \frac {k[x,y,z]}{\left<(x-1)z\right>}$ 
where $k$ is an algebraically closed field. I guess I'm searching for some ideals that will result in a field but I can't see how to do this.

[EDIT: Thanks to MooS for the correction]

Comment: $k[x,y,z]/\langle (x-1)z\rangle$ or $k[x,y,z]/\langle x-1,z\rangle$? In the first ring, $\langle y \rangle$ is not even prime. The second ring is isomorphic to $k[y]$.

Comment: I've corrected the question and now I am hunting for two maximal ideals! Thanks for the correction.

Comment: You should think geometrically. Do you know the geometric interpretation of maximal ideals of $k[x,y,z]/I$?

Comment: I think the nullstellensatz says that they should correspond to points? If so can I somehow take the points over to $R$?

Comment: You should be able to find plenty of points on the affine variety given by $(x-1)z=0$. All those points correspond to maximal ideals in your ring $R$.

Comment: Would an example of a point be (1,5,0) say? Just to see if I've got the idea correct?

Comment: Yes, but note that you dont need $x=1$ **AND** $z=0$. One of them is enough, i.e. $(2,5,0)$ is also an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the quotient of $R$ by the ideal $(x-z)$, and that ideal contains $(x-1)(x-z)+(x-1)z=(x-1)x$, and you can show $x$ is a nontrivial idempotent of the quotient.

So, $R/(x-z)$ has a nontrivial idempotent $\implies$ $R/(x-z)$ is not local $\implies$ $R$ is not local.

Comment: The geometric interpretation in the comments is very interesting too, although that isn't my forte. I think this reasoning works even if the field is not algebraically closed, though....

Comment: Your interpretation is also geometric. Forgetting about the third dimension ($y$ plays no role at all here), $R$ is the union of 2 lines. If you intersect it with a general line (thats what you do, when you divide out $x-z$), you get two distinct points, i.e. you get idempotents.

My reasoning also works if $k$ is not algebraically closed, since any point still gives you a maximal ideal. In the non-algebraically closed case, there are even more maximal ideals (which does not bother us at all, if we want to show that the ring is not local).

Comment: @MooS Ahh, OK, I thought the conclusion about points might require algebraic closedness. Thanks for spending the time to tell me about these lines of thought (pun?)
. It is extremely interesting and definitely something I want to learn more about. I hope you won't hesitatate to give me more pointers like these when you see the chance. My current knowledge of rings is very structural and not very interpretive.